# How to make tensordot operations after permutation

Tags: pytorch, permute, tensordot

I have 2 tensors, A and B:

```
A = torch.randn([32,128,64,12],dtype=torch.float64)
B = torch.randn([64,12,64,12],dtype=torch.float64)
C = torch.tensordot(A,B,([2,3],[0,1]))
D = C.permute(0,2,1,3) # shape:[32,64,128,12]
```

tensor D comes from the operations "tensordot -> permute". How can I implement a new operation f() to make the tensordot operation after f() like:

```
A_2 = f(A)
B_2 = f(B)
D = torch.tensordot(A_2,B_2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html#torch.einsum) which is very flexible?

```py
D = torch.einsum('ijab,abkl->ikjl', A, B)
```

The problem with `tensordot` is that it outputs all dimensions of `A` before those of `B` and what you are looking for (when permuting) is to "interleave" dimensions from `A` and `B`.

Comment: Yes! I indeed use "torch.einsum" at last.